# Having trouble figuring out how to create a special condition

Tags: css

Hi I have these this blocks of code :

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <dt class="complete">
   </dt>
</div>
```

That dynamically changes to this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <dt class="complete">
   </dt>
   <dd class="complete">
   </dd>
</div>
```

I want to make the background color of the dt.complete to be white when it does not have a sibling dd.complete.

When there IS a sibling dd.complete, I want to specify dt.complete to have a gray background.

How do I create this condition? I am using sass and compass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt {
    &.complete {
       background-color: gray;
       &:only-child {
           background-color: white;
       }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KSuVt/)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about only child, this worked!

Comment: glad i could help! if this answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark in the upper left to mark it as resolved. welcome to stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an adjacent selector, `+` to target the sibling.

```
dt + dd {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

This will target any `dd` that follows a `dt`. The earlier case is trickier, but you can use an `only-child selector`. [Check this out](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-onlychild).

```
dt:only-child {
    background-color: gray;
}
```